# Complex Root of Unity Analogue of Forward Difference Operator

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

In my studies I have come across a couple of operators; in particular;

$$\Delta[f(x)]=f(x+1)-f(x)$$
$$\Delta^*[f(x)]=f(x+1)+f(x)$$

$\Delta$ has been called the Forward Difference Operator.  I was curious to see if there is any literature that relates into the complex plane and relates complex roots of unity.  For example, we can rewrite

$$\Delta[f(x)]=f(x+1)-f(x)=f\left[\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right]-f\left[\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

But if we let $w_k=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{k}}$ it can be rewritten as

$$\Delta[f(x)]=f\left[\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{w_2^0}{2}\right]+w_2f\left[\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{w_2}{2}\right]$$

THus, higher order difference operators would involve linear combinations of complex roots of unity, and appear as

$$\Delta_{N}[f(x)]=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-j}\cdot f\left[\left(x+\frac{1}{N}\right)+\frac{w_N^j}{N}\right]$$

Finally, as there were two operators above, both $\Delta$ and $\Delta^*$, we can consider a positive integer $k$ with $k<N$ and the operators would be

$$\Delta_{N}^k[f(x)]=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}w_N^{-kj}\cdot f\left[\left(x+\frac{1}{N}\right)+\frac{w_N^j}{N}\right]$$

Thus, the three operators for $k=0,1,2$ and $N=3$ would be

$$\Delta_3^0[f(x)]=f\left(x+\frac{2}{3}\right)+f\left(x+\frac{1+w_3}{3}\right)+f\left(x+\frac{1+w_3^2}{3}\right)$$

$$\Delta_3^1[f(x)]=f\left(x+\frac{2}{3}\right)+w_3^2f\left(x+\frac{1+w_3}{3}\right)+w_3f\left(x+\frac{1+w_3^2}{3}\right)$$

$$\Delta_3^2[f(x)]=f\left(x+\frac{2}{3}\right)+w_3f\left(x+\frac{1+w_3}{3}\right)+w_3^2f\left(x+\frac{1+w_3^2}{3}\right)$$

Are there any papers or books around that contain such operators in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You might find something relevant in one of these two books, or others like them published in the mid-19th century: [**The Calculus of Operations**](https://archive.org/details/calculusoperati01pategoog) by John Paterson (1850) *AND* [**A Treatise on the Calculus of Operations**](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseoncalc00carmgoog) by Robert Carmichael (1855)